# Change width of select element for each active option

Tags: html, css

I have a `select` element that lays directly up against an input. It looks great for the most part, but there's too much whitespace on some of the options. It seems like unless I set some static width myself, `select` expands to the width of its largest option.

I want to make it so that the select option only takes up as much width as the currently displayed option. I'd ask if it's possible, but I know it is somehow because I've seen it on [Amazon's homepage](https://www.amazon.com/) on their search bar. The behavior of the `select` that controls their search filter is essentially what I'm trying to recreate on my website, but I can't figure out exactly what they did. Here's the code that reproduces the basic idea of what I've got currently.

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Consoles</option>
  <option>Games</option>
  <option>Equipment</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />
```

CSS:

```
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 44px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

I have a fiddle with everything [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y82x60fa/2/) as well.

I know I could use JavaScript to make it work, but that would be an absolute last resort in my mind. I want to do it in pure HTML and CSS if I can. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even just getting `text-align: center` to work would be huge.

Comment: If you inspect Amazon's element, you will see that they are using fake "select". They call it nav-search-facade. It seems that browsers don't like `select` element and it's quite hard to style it :)

Comment: You're right. I didn't see that. I can see now that they made the select transparent. Shoot. It looks like they might have had to use javascript to change the value inside their fake select. I was hoping for a cleaner solution, but javascript might just have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the thing that you want exactly. But since the `<select>` width need to be calculated or determined with another value, it is required some JavaScripts. I used pure jQuery and did some changes to your HTML and CSS.

The answer to your problem is, you need to append your selected option to another select option to get the current option width and keep it until the next change of the select.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-div">
<select id="resized">
  <option value="All">All</option>
  <option value="Consoles">Consoles</option>
  <option value="Games">Games</option>
  <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />
</div>

<!-- hidden select to calculate the selected option width -->

<select id="hidden_select">
  <option id="hidden_select_option"></option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

input {
  height: 44px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#main-div{
  display: none;
  width: 375px;
}

#hidden_select {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#resized').change();
    $("#main-div").css("display", "block");
});
 $('#resized').on("change", function(){
    $("#hidden_select_option").html($("#resized option:selected").text());
    $(this).width($("#hidden_select").width());

    //fix the input filed width
    var x = $("#main-div").width();
    var y = $(this).width() + 21;
    $("input").width((x-y) - 12);
 });
```

**Note:** values 21 and 12 are your padding values and border values of select and input.

**Working Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/y82x60fa/10/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with simple jquery. On [Amazon's home page](https://www.amazon.com/) is also done with js or other scripting language.

```js
 $('#resizingSelectTag').change(function(){
    $("#widthTempOption").html($('#resizingSelectTag option:selected').text());
    $(this).width($("#selectTagWidth").width()); 
 });
```

```css
#resizingSelectTag {
 width: 50px;
}
  
#selectTagWidth{
 display : none;
} 
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
 position:absolute;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 44px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="resizingSelectTag">
      <option>All</option>
       <option>Lorem Ipsum</option>
       <option>Lorem Ipsum is</option>
</select>

<select id="selectTagWidth">
       <option id="widthTempOption"></option>
</select>
<input type="text" />
```